# Displaying multiple/All channel entries on single page

Tags: channel-entries

When I try to set my limit to 3, 4, or anything, my page is simply displaying the same entry over and over, rather than showing all the different entries.  Please help!

```
{entries_start_1}
{entries_1}
<div id="content-left">
    {exp:channel:entries orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="3" dynamic="no"}
        {entry2_image}
        {title}</br>
        {entry_date format='%F %d %Y'}
        {entry2_intro}
        {entry2_body}       
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
{entries_column_divider}
Recent Post
{embed="includes/.sub_nav" section_channel="{section_channel}"}
{entries_end}
```

Comment: thanks jrothafer!  Can you help?

Comment: What are your '{entries_start_1}', '{entries_1}' tags?

Answer (score 0):

For the most part things look ok.
You should set the channel= parameter.
If that doesn't help, try the channel entries loop by itself in an empty template.